# General `NodeJs/express` Error when declaring routes (TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at pathtoRegexp)

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new at `node.js`, and this error cost me many efforts of investigations so I'm sharing this.

I've only tried to declare the `express` and some basic routers in my index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/api/courses', (req, res)=>{
    res.send(courses);
});

app.get('/api/courses:id', (req, res)=>{
    const course = courses.find(c => c.id === parseInt(req.params.id));
    if (!course) res.send('The given id was not found...');
    res.send(course);   
});

app.get();
```

The error details:

> \node_modules\path-to-regexp\index.js:63   path = ('^' + path +
>   (strict ? '' : path[path.length - 1] === '/' ? '?' : '/?'))
>                                               ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>       at pathtoRegexp (C:\Users...\node_modules\path-to-regexp\index.js:63:49)
>       at new Layer (C:\Users...\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:45:17)
>       at Function.route (C:\Users...\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:494:15)
>       at Function.app.(anonymous function) [as get] (C:\Users...\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:481:30)
>       at Object. (C:...\index.js:24:5)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `app.get();` causes the error.

As the [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.get.method) says, the `app.get(path, callback [, callback ...])`
 must have a path argument (also `app.get(name)` must have name argument).

Answer (score 5):

The reason behind that error is using the `app.get()` method without param, which expect the endpoint url and call back as parameters.

Answer (score 3):

I also recently faced this issue and it was because my project requires .env file which has all the base routes defined and somehow it was deleted from project.
So my finding for this issue is check for all config/.env files which your node.js requires.

Answer (score 2):

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/api/courses', (req, res)=>{
    res.send(courses);
});

app.get('/api/courses:id', (req, res)=>{
    const course = courses.find(c => c.id === parseInt(req.params.id));
    if (!course) res.send('The given id was not found...');
    res.send(course);   
});

app.get(); // <= Remove this line of code and it will work. you need the path parameter in order for a app.get() to work
```

Comment: It's considered good to include a brief explanation of the code and why it solves the question.

Comment: I did do that. I put it on the last line of the code with a comment.

Answer (score 0):

probably check app.get()  and app.post()  is being left any perimeter try to comment it and check
As the documentation says, the app.get(path, callback [, callback ...])
must have a path argument (also app.get(name) must have name argument).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).